# skipping ENUM column after inserting a new record

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, enums, entity-framework-core

EF Core with Postgres is skipping ENUM column after inserting a new record, and default value is getting saved in the DB.

I am trying to add new record to postgres table EncounterBatchItem. It seems that its skipping the enum value while inserting and taking the default value 'Processed'

```
public enum EncounterBatchItemStatus
{
    Invalid,
    Processed
}

public class EncounterBatchItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int EncounterBatchId { get; set; }
    public int EncounterId { get; set; }
    public EncounterBatchItemStatus Status { get; set; }
    public long Balance { get; set; }
}
```

```
builder.Property(x => x.Status)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("enum_encounter_batch_item_status")
            .HasColumnName("status")
            .HasDefaultValue(EncounterBatchItemStatus.Processed)
            .HasConversion<EncounterBatchItemStatus>();
```

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE TYPE enum_encounter_batch_item_status AS ENUM (
                                'Invalid',
                                'Processed');");
```

```
var encounterBatchItem = new EncounterBatchItem
     {
         EncounterBatchId = 136,
         EncounterId = 17,
         Balance = 1000,
         Errors = new List<EncounterBatchItemError>(),
         Status = EncounterBatchItemStatus.Invalid
     };

await _context.EncounterBatchItems.AddAsync(encounterBatchItem, cancellationToken);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

When I checked the SQL insert script, for some reason it's skipping the `status` column:

```
INSERT INTO encounter_batch_item (balance, encounter_batch_id, encounter_id, errors)
VALUES (@p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)
RETURNING id, status;
```

By changing the `Status` to nullable, it works, but `Status` is a required column, so I don't want to make it nullable.

```
public class EncounterBatchItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int EncounterBatchId { get; set; }
    public int EncounterId { get; set; }
    public EncounterBatchItemStatus? Status { get; set; }
    public long Balance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `EncounterBatchItemStatus.Invalid` the same thing as `default(EncounterBatchItemStatus)`? If so, that's probably the reason: because EF can't differentate between `default(EncounterBatchItemStatus)` (in which case it will use the SQL `DEFAULT` you set in `HasDefaultValue()`) - or an explicit `Invalid` value.

Comment: Hi @Dai I am providing an explicit value Invalid while inserting record

Comment: Yes, but do you understand my point about how that’s _undetectable_?

Comment: @Dai I am trying to understand, do you have some links stating this issue, any ideas what is the resolution, do I change the default value of enum by changing order of values?

Comment: Try remove `HasDefaultValue`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I want to provide default value Processed if no value is passed while adding new record

Comment: Then replace with `HasDefaultValueSql`.

Comment: Hi @Dai can you tell me what change I need to do

Comment: @Dai Thanks for providing direction, resolved using this link https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15070

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MapEnum` method to configure this mapping, see https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=without-datasource

```
var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(/* connection string */);
dataSourceBuilder.MapEnum<Mood>();
var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(dataSource));
```

Comment: I have already added the mapping

Comment: .MapEnum<EncounterBatchItemStatus>("enum_encounter_batch_item_status", new NpgsqlNullNameTranslator());

Comment: Here is working sample https://gist.github.com/navferty/1cdc6e361c5b5565c6023d61b95a499e

Comment: it doesn't work at my end, I have the same code as urs posted in the question, also the Status column has default Processed